# How do I judge whether the socket is connected or not?

Tags: sockets, automated-tests, loadrunner

I'm using the HP Loadrunner to test socket protocol program,now I send some hexadecimal number system to the server,but I have no idea to judge whether the socket is connected or not,I paste my script below down here

```
#define _EOF '#'
#include "lrs.h"

Action()
{
 char *recvbuf;
 int recvlen=0;
 int rc;
 lr_think_time(1000);
 lr_start_transaction("Trans_socket");
 lrs_set_recv_timeout (1,500);
 lr_start_transaction("Conn_socket");


 rc = lrs_create_socket("socket0", "TCP", "LocalHost=0", "RemoteHost=192.168.10.110:10001", LrsLastArg);  

 lr_output_message("rc=%d",rc);

    if (rc != 0 ) 
{
    lr_end_transaction("Conn_socket", LR_FAIL);
    lr_end_transaction("Trans_socket", LR_FAIL);
    return 0;
}
    lr_end_transaction("Conn_socket", LR_PASS);  

    lr_rendezvous("trace");

    lrs_send("socket0","buf0", LrsLastArg);

    lrs_receive ("socket0","buf1",LrsLastArg);

    lrs_get_last_received_buffer ("socket0",&recvbuf,&recvlen);

 if(recvlen==58)
     lr_end_transaction("Trans_socket", LR_PASS);
 else
     lr_end_transaction ("Trans_socket", LR_FAIL);

lrs_send("socket0", "buf2", LrsLastArg);

lrs_receive("socket0", "buf3", LrsLastArg);

lrs_send("socket0", "buf4", LrsLastArg);

lrs_receive("socket0", "buf5", LrsLastArg);
lr_think_time(100);

lrs_send("socket0", "buf6", LrsLastArg);
lr_think_time(1000);

lrs_receive("socket0", "buf7", LrsLastArg);
lr_think_time(1000);

lrs_send("socket0", "buf8", LrsLastArg);

lrs_receive("socket0", "buf9", LrsLastArg);

lrs_close_socket("socket0");

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> ,but I have no idea to judge whether the socket is connected

It is time to hire a sockets programmer who has been there and done that.

You also have some extremely odd conventions in your code from a loadrunner perspective.   You appear to be treating user think time as delays while waiting for a server response in your code which would indicate conceptual issues in the use of the tool.  Your use of a rendezvous is a key indicator of a model violation in its common use, where the tool is being used to break the chaotic nature of end users arriving and departing at different points in time.

Comment: Can you show me how the script works?I only want to know if the socket is connected,thanks a lot

Comment: You want to know whether your end of the socket pair is connected, or whether the peer is still reachable?

Comment: yes,can you give me a hand?or you can give me a example?thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Enable continue on error
2. Check socket attributes
3. Disable continue on error

For example

```
char* peer;
lr_continue_on_error(1);
lrs_create_socket("socket1", "TCP", "LocalHost=0", "RemoteHost=fakehost",  LrsLastArg);
peer =lrs_get_socket_attrib("socket1", REMOTE_ADDRESS );
if (peer == NULL){
    lr_message("Not connected");
}else{
    lr_message("Connected");
}

lr_continue_on_error(0);
```